# Soldering wires in place of mini USB

Tags: usb, soldering

I'm working on a project that I need to take up as less space as possible. One of the components included a mini USB port that I have desoldered.

[image: Board with mini USB removed]

The only problem is that the pads are too small. I can easily tin the wires and from there solder a connection to the pads, but it kind of becomes a mess. Are there any methods to reliably solder some wires to the 5 pads or maybe a set of pins with the right spacing that have wires on one end? That way I would just need to align them correctly and solder it.

Comment: Depending on what this device is, you only need 4. GND (which you can get anywhere) +5V, DP and DM, which looks like 2 big test pads are available for. The shield around the outside (the oblong holes) are probably attached to the ground plane. The only other thing you need to do is +5V, which is probably on one side of that capacitor. Now you just have to worry about ruining the trace impedance...

Comment: solid wires are tidier than flex wires, but less durable if they are made to flex.

Comment: Mini USB isn't exactly big, so you aren't likely going to find some other connector with the same pitch taking less space. So what are you trying to achieve here, get something you can use as working prototype, or something that will enter live production? For messy prototypes, you could attempt using something like a simple header strip, either a SMD version or a THR mounted "on the side". This is 2mm pitch or something.

Comment: @Lundin Is there something you would be able to recommend that I could try for a prototype? After a bit of searching, I found that for mini USBs, the pitch is 0.8mm and obviously 5 positions/pins, but the problem is I can't find anything with those specifications. Everything either has less/more pins or is the wrong pitch length. This one would've been nice if it had the right pitch and pin length. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/jst-sales-america-inc/B4B-XH-A(LF)(SN)/455-2249-ND/1651047

Comment: @Matt I'd probably go for hand-soldering wires in that case, since 0.8mm isn't really a standard pitch. Single strand wires are often easiest to work with for such fine pitch. Though speaking of JST, they got lots of fine pitch stuff, so they might have something. Check JST and Molex.

Answer (score 2):

There are flat ribbon cables available with various pitches like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/3m/3749-10-100/3M156019-1-ND/8256278).

I wouldn't solder a cable on such small pads, though. There's a risk of "peeling" of the pads when the cable is "moving around".

An alternative is to solder magnet wires. They are solid copper wires having a coating (enamell) layer and are lighter than ribbon cables.

Comment: Magnet wires (or magnet wire). Magnetic wires means the wires have been magnetized so they are magnets (like fridge magnets). Magnet wire is a type of wire which is used to make electro-magnets.

Comment: @user253751 ah, my mistake. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Magnet wire is a solid bet, I second that

Comment: I doubt magnet wires are called that because they are magnetised, rather than simply because they are used in the making of coils for motors and electromagnets. The advantage of this type of wire is very small cross section with thin insulation, perfect for windings - because the magnetic field is caused by Ampere-turns and channeled through the ferromagnetic core. Magnetisation of the wire is out of the equation.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said what the other end of the wires would connect to.

I've done this a couple of different ways.

1) Use 30 AWG wire-wrap wire soldered to the pads.  Tin the pads, strip about 0.75mm of insulation from the Kynar wire-wrap wire and tin with solder, add a touch of flux to the solder pads on the board, then sweat the wires into place.  Do one wire at a time.

A microscope makes this easy.  Be sure to provide some form of strain-relief for the wires.

2) Use a flex PCB with the correct footprint to match the pad spacing.  We build a product that does exactly this.  The USB connector is removed from the original board, then the flex strip PCB is soldered to the original pads.

In our case, the flex strip PCB also includes strain-relief points that solder to the original mounting pads of the USB connector.

I'll update this answer with photos after I take them.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a small connector with epoxy resin and copper foil in v shape to extend the 5 pads to a connector. try DIY connectors

Answer (score 0):

for 0.8mm pitch with 5 circuit board to wire connector - [follow the link](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1718811.pdf).

I think this is apt as per your description. side entry type connector.

Answer (score 0):

A stripped-and-tinned USB cable will typically have 26ga wire, very easily solderable onto the mini-USB pads. If you go that way, ensure that there is some strain relief on the cable to prevent an inadvertent tug from pulling the pads up.

To make this easier, pre-align the wires using a small jig, then tape them together with Kapton tape to hold them at the right spacing and in the right sequence. Then place this on your board and solder.

If this board is something you're making yourself, consider changing to Micro-B connector. It's very low profile and should satisfy your mechanical constraints.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the easiest way is to solder a PCB pin header connector with a suitable pitch, for example [HN1X5-1.27](https://store.comet.bg/download-file.php?id=1959) (or similar) and plug it into a relevant socket header connector (PN1X5-1.27) with soldered cable. The exact pitch is not very critical, since the number of pins is only 5 and it is sufficient to match the middle pin. If the other pins do not match, they can be slightly bent before soldering to fit the PCB pads. Once the middle pin is soldered, it is easy with the rest of the pins.